# Can (How do) you unset an environment variable on execution?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Many people are familiar with this method of setting env vars:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/lib python do-a-thing.py
```

But I want to ensure the variable is *unset* before calling my command. Is it possible to do this in a one-line invocation, or do I have to do it this way?

```
unset PYTHONPATH; python do-a-thing.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `env` for unsetting (or setting) environment variables: "The env utility executes another utility after modifying the environment as specified on the command line."

```
env -u PYTHONPATH python do-a-thing.py
```

Best thing is: this won't modify your *current* execution environment.

(Edit: apparently `-u` is a FreeBSD extension... please let us know if this works under Linux, too!)

Comment: Looks like this works for me!

Comment: +1. I confirm it works under `Debian GNU/Linux 8` and `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.